# payment process without leaving the site with paypal and php

Tags: php, paypal, payment-processing

i want to use paypal as my payment gateway with php.

I want that my site user should not be redirected to paypal website for the payment process.

Is there any way t do this.

And also i want to make payment with credit card only.

Thanks in advance

Avinash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to choose appropriate integration method for that:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_overview

Comment: what is the appropriate method?